# What counts as a transaction on the free API license?

Tags: alchemyapi

I'm working on a book for Manning and want to use Alchemy News API as part of one of the examples. I have a free license which says it allows for 1,000 transactions per day. Does that mean 1,000 queries or something else? I hit the limit today way earlier than I expected to, at significantly less than 1,000 queries.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about licensing, not about programming.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you're not asking Alchemy this question? It's not a programming question, so it's off-topic here. It's a licensing question, and they're the only ones who can answer it.

Comment: Good point. I'd gone to their site to ask the question but noticed a link they provided to SO as an option for asking questions, but you're right it isn't a programming question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each type of call has different amounts of transactions it uses. The text analysis uses just 1 transaction but the image analysis uses more. I believe it used about 5 transactions per image but it's been awhile since I've used the image recognition.

The number of transactions used is given in the response from AlchemyAPI. It also gives you more details in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

**Query Cost + Result Cost = Total Cost**

This is something I learnt today. Therefore you'll run out of transactions easily with loads of data. Keep your queries to a minimum.